# Title of Items in Fragment Showing URL of NAME of Website in Android Studio - Master/Detail Flow

Tags: android, android-studio, master-detail

the items in my fragment in my Master/Detail Flow layout in Android Studio are showing the urls of my websites instead of the Title of the websites. In my DummyItem class in the DummyContent java file, it has the id variable, website_name variable, and the website_url variable but for some reason when I run it in the virtual device, on the left hand side in the fragment it shows the urls instead of the website_name I created for each item.

Here's my DummyContent class:

```
package net.androidbootcamp.modernartmuseums.dummy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class DummyContent {

/**
 * An array of sample (dummy) items.
 */
public static final List<DummyItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<DummyItem>();

/**
 * A map of sample (dummy) items, by ID.
 */
public static final Map<String, DummyItem> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, 
DummyItem>();

private static final int COUNT = 25;

static {
    // Add some sample items.
    addItem(new DummyItem("1", "Barnes Museum", 
"http://www.barnesfoundation.org"));
    addItem(new DummyItem("2", "Tate Modern", "http://www.tate.org.uk"));
    addItem(new DummyItem("3", "Van Gogh Museum", 
"http://www.vangoghmuseum.nl/en" ));
    }


private static void addItem(DummyItem item) {
    ITEMS.add(item);
    ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
}

private static DummyItem createDummyItem (int position) {
    return new DummyItem(String.valueOf(position), "Item " + position, 
makeDetails(position));
}

private static String makeDetails(int position) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("Details about Item: ").append(position);
    for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
        builder.append("\nMore details information here.");
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

/**
 * A dummy item representing a piece of content.
 */
public static class DummyItem {
    public String id;
    public String website_name;
    public  String website_url;

    public DummyItem(String id, String website_name, String website_url) {
        this.id = id;
        this.website_name = website_name;
        this.website_url = website_url;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return website_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my ItemDetailFragment class:

```
package net.androidbootcamp.modernartmuseums;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.TextView;

import net.androidbootcamp.modernartmuseums.dummy.DummyContent;

public class ItemDetailFragment extends Fragment {
/**
 * The fragment argument representing the item ID that this fragment
 * represents.
 */
public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";

/**
 * The dummy content this fragment is presenting.
 */
private DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public ItemDetailFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
        // Load the dummy content specified by the fragment
        // arguments. In a real-world scenario, use a Loader
        // to load content from a content provider.
        mItem = 
DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));

        Activity activity = this.getActivity();
        CollapsingToolbarLayout appBarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) 
activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
        if (appBarLayout != null) {
            appBarLayout.setTitle(mItem.website_name);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_detail, container, 
false);

    getActivity().setTitle("home");


    WebView webView;

    // Show the dummy content as text in a TextView.
    if (mItem.id.equals("1")) {
         webView = ((WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail));
         webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
         webView.loadUrl(mItem.website_url);

    }

    if (mItem.id.equals("2")) {
        webView = ((WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail));
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl(mItem.website_url);

    }

    if (mItem.id.equals("3")) {
        webView = ((WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail));
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl(mItem.website_url);

        }

    return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you posted the "details" fragment in your question but you're complaining about the urls instead of names being present in the fragment "on the left hand side" which would be the master fragment. Please post the code of that fragment if this is the case.

Comment: Where is the master fragment located in android studio?

Comment: I changed the word "content" to something else in my code and I think I messed everything up. OTL

Comment: @Luksprog Can you please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: You should have two fragments in your code, ItemDetailFragment which shows the details and another fragment which will show a list of the DummyItems(which you should post). The urls appear in that list fragment right?

Comment: I found out what was wrong. In ItemListActivity in onBindViewHolder it was  holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).website_url); instead of holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).website_name);

Comment: Thank you though. I'm relatively new to this, so I hope I didn't mess anything up.